# Are there any official or tried and true methods to translating D&D 3.5e creatures to 5E?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-3.5e, conversion, monster-design

I play 5E almost exclusively, now, and while I love the resources out there, I have many a miniature from other editions that is now stat-blockless. I've scoured the internet already, so I think I know the answer but figured it wouldn't hurt to ask:

**Are there any official methods to translate a 3.5 statblock to 5E?**

I'm looking for spell replacements, AC or HP adjustments, XP translations, anything that can help me stay true to the flavor, feel, and challenge the monster presented in it's original game. If there is something published by WotC out there, that's the preferred answer here, but assuming there isn't I'd settle for tried and true tips and tricks. Ideally I'd want a true method by which to approach the problem so I don't have to spend an hour looking over every detail of the monster.

Comment: As an alternative, you could perform such a conversion yourself and post the results in a separate question asking *Is this* 5e *conversion of this* 3.5 *monster balanced?*

Comment: To really do that right and boil it down to a "method" we're talking about hours of work for me, which is precisely what I'm trying to avoid by asking my question. :-P

Comment: To be honest it won't take that much work (depending on the monster). I've converted monsters accross entirely different systems in minutes, with system mastery granted, but it shouldn't take you hours.

Comment: That's totally fair. I wasn't trying to dis the question or anything. I was just thinking that were you to offer even a very rough estimate of a conversion (even if your conversion is something like *I think it's pretty much a gnoll except with this special ability* or something) folks may be inclined to explain the ins and outs of their own feelings about *your* conversion, and knowing *their* thoughts could inform how you make *future* conversions.

Comment: Assuming a 15 AC in 3.5 = a 15 AC in 5E. But I can't say with certainty that is true. Hence my question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Yes

Wizards have written [this](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/DnD_Conversions_1.0.pdf) handy and pragmatic guide.

The last page has advice for translating monster statblocks under "Quick Conversions".

> For first and second edition, you can use the shorthand monster statistics in the adventure. In these adventures, monsters are often more numerous, but they typically deal lower damage and have fewer hit points than their fifth edition counterparts. Make the following changes to those first- and second-edition monsters...

and

> In third edition, you can use monster statistics included in an adventure as a guide. Monster distribution in this edition is fairly close to the distribution in fifth edition. in earlier editions, such creatures often deal lower damage and have fewer hit points than their fifth edition counterparts. Most statistics in third edition include the creature’s ability scores. Use the following parameters...

Comment: Good find! (although I disagree with some of the methods Wizards suggests using).

Comment: Yeah, the other answer wasn't bad, it just wasn't exactly what was asked for. It's a shame it seems to be deleted.

Comment: That was my answer. I deleted it since I didn't like the tone it took. Seemed a little more dismissive than helpful. I may edit it and undelete later.

Comment: Please do, AFAIK house rules and homebrew are welcome here, as long as they're clearly labeled as such.